# Maximum number of iscsi connections

Tags: windows, iscsi

Is there a way to increase the maximum number of iscsi connections on windows to avoid this error?
Connect-IscsiTarget : Exceeded max sessions for this initiator.

Answer (score 1):

As said on the [official page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/dn659435%28v=ws.11%29) : the maximum iSCSI target instances per iSCSI Target Server is 256 :/

Comment: Is that for windows servers 2012 only?

Comment: No, same for 2022+
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/iscsi/iscsi-target-server-limits

Comment: is the problem related to number of iscsi target instance ???